# Add date in woocommerce checkout page custom field

Tags: php, wordpress, datetime, woocommerce, e-commerce

I am trying to add custom select option in woocommerce checkout page.  It is adding the extra field but I want to add the date in the value of the select option.

Is there any solution for this?

**Here is the code I added in my theme function.php**

```
$today = new DateTime();
$tomorrow = new DateTime();
$tomorrow->modify('+1 day');
$dayAfterTomorrow = new DateTime();
$dayAfterTomorrow->modify('+2 day');

add_action( 'woocommerce_after_order_notes', 'my_custom_checkout_field' );

function my_custom_checkout_field( $checkout ) {
    echo '<div id="my_custom_checkout_field"><h2>' . __('My Field') . '</h2>';

    woocommerce_form_field( 'my_field_name', array(
        'type'          => 'select',
        'class'         => array('my-field-class form-row-wide'),
        'label'         => __('Fill in this field'),
        'placeholder'   => __(''),
        'options'     => array(
          'Today' => __("This should be today's date"),
          'Tomorrow' => __('This should be tomorrow date'),
          'Day After Tomorrow' => __('This should be Day After Tomorrow Date')
        )), $checkout->get_value( 'my_field_name' ));
    echo '</div>';
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate? I don't quite understand what you are asking? What is wrong with the code you posted?

Comment: I want the option value "Today" to be today's date.

Comment: Ok, so you need to put the date in the `options` array. The 'key' is what is *currently* "Today"... this is probably what you'd save in the DB, and the array value is what is displayed on the page. See also the `[date()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function.

Comment: Also, see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35018044/adding-a-datepicker-to-woocommerce-checkout-page) as it's very similar.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `date()` and `strtotime()` you can  set the `options` as follows:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_order_notes', 'my_custom_checkout_field' );

function my_custom_checkout_field( $checkout ) {
    echo '<div id="my_custom_checkout_field"><h2>' . __('My Field') . '</h2>';

    $today = strtotime('today');
    $tomorrow = strtotime('tomorrow');
    $dayAfterTomorrow = strtotime('+2 days');

    woocommerce_form_field( 'my_field_name', array(
        'type'          => 'select',
        'class'         => array('my-field-class form-row-wide'),
        'label'         => __('Fill in this field'),
        'placeholder'   => __(''),
        'options'     => array(
            date( 'yyyy-mm-dd', $today ) => date( get_option('date_format'), $today ),
            date( 'yyyy-mm-dd', $tomorrow ) => date( get_option('date_format'), $tomorrow ),
            date( 'yyyy-mm-dd', $dayAfterTomorrow ) => date( get_option('date_format'), $dayAfterTomorrow ),
        )));
    echo '</div>';
}
```

This will allow you to later on save dates as in the format **YYYY-MM-DD**. I wrote a tutorial on [customizing the checkout fields](https://www.kathyisawesome.com/woocommerce-customize-checkout-fields/) that you may find useful.