# wrong date appearance as custom field

Tags: php, date, woocommerce, action

I just tried to add a "Delivery Date" to WooCommerce checkout process based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41468093/4170774) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63394854/4170774) threads.

This is the related code to print delivery date on order meta and view it on Thank you page and also admin order page:

```
//Shipping (Delivery) Date


// Add custom checkout datepicker field

add_action( 'woocommerce_before_order_notes', 'checkout_display_datepicker_custom_field' );
function checkout_display_datepicker_custom_field( $checkout ) {
    $field_id = 'my_datepicker';

    echo '<div id="datepicker-wrapper">';

    $today = strtotime('today');
    $tomorrow = strtotime('tomorrow');
    $dayAfterTomorrow = strtotime('+2 days');

    woocommerce_form_field(  $field_id, array(
        'type'          => 'select',
        'class'         => array('my-field-class form-row-wide'),
        'label' => __('Choose a date'),
        'placeholder'   => __('Select delivery date'),
        'required' => true, // Or false
        'options'     => array(
            '' => 'Select',
            date( 'yyyy-mm-dd', $today ) => date( get_option('date_format'), $today ),
            date( 'yyyy-mm-dd', $tomorrow ) => date( get_option('date_format'), $tomorrow ),
            date( 'yyyy-mm-dd', $dayAfterTomorrow ) => date( get_option('date_format'), $dayAfterTomorrow ),
        )));

    echo '<br></div>';

}



// Save field

add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_create_order', 'save_datepicker_custom_field_value', 10, 2 );
function save_datepicker_custom_field_value( $order, $data ){
    $field_id = 'my_datepicker';
    $meta_key = '_'.$field_id;

    if ( isset($_POST[$field_id]) && ! empty($_POST[$field_id]) ) {
        $date = esc_attr($_POST[$field_id]);
        
        $order->update_meta_data( $meta_key, $date ); // Save date as order meta data
        
        $note = sprintf(__("Chosen date for Thank you page: %s.", "woocommerce"), $date );
        $note = isset($data['order_comments']) && ! empty($data['order_comments']) ? $data['order_comments'] . '. ' . $note : $note;
        
        // Save date on customer order note
        $order->set_customer_note( $note );

    }
}
```

It prints choosed date but in a wrong format like: **20202020-1212-2424**

How can I modify this bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the wrong format on your `date()` functions.
Have a look at [date/time format](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php#refsect1-datetime.format-parameters) docs.

In your case, `yyyy-mm-dd`:

- `y` A two digit representation of a year
- `m` Numeric representation of a month, with leading zeros
- `d` Day of the month, 2 digits with leading zeros

Hence, `20202020-1212-2424`.

You probably meant `2020-12-24`, which should be `Y-m-d`:

- `Y` A full numeric representation of a year, 4 digits